# How to save changes to my orginal image in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, image

I'm using this code to save image

```
 PictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath)
```

after that I crop image and I want to save it again by replacing the old one with the new cropped one

any help please

regards,,,

Comment: How do you load the image?

Comment: If you use `Image.FromFile()` you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250848/how-to-prevent-the-image-fromfile-method-to-lock-the-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's the answer

```html
Dim bmp1 As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
        If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath)
        End If

        bmp1.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        ' Dispose of the image files.
        bmp1.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code when you load the image into the PictureBox instead of the one you are currently using and you'll be fine just saving later. The using statement ensures the file is released once the image is loaded.
Replace filePath with your own.

```
Using stream as new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
End Using
```

### EDIT

From your last comment I can see this code

```
Try 
    Me.Opacity = 0% 
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = cc() 
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath) 
    source = Image.FromFile(filePath) 
    PictureBox1.Image = source 
    TextBox1.Text = filePath 
    Me.Opacity = 100% 
Catch ex As Exception 
    MsgBox(ex.Message) 
End Try
```

You don't need to reload the image to the PictureBox after saving. Just get rid of the following lines.

```
source = Image.FromFile(filePath) 
PictureBox1.Image = source
```

That should solve your problem at least for now as you won't be saving the image to the same image you load it from (you didn't actually load it). But you will have to find a better solution for your whole algorithm later :)

Comment: I've tried to do so but I met this error {"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\image20170627083237.png' because it is being used by another process."}

Comment: OK this is the code that I am using it and where should I put your code      Try

            Me.Opacity = 0%
            Me.PictureBox1.Image = cc()
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath)
            source = Image.FromFile(filePath)
            PictureBox1.Image = source

            TextBox1.Text = filePath
            Me.Opacity = 100%

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

Comment: What does your cc() function do?

Comment: Private Function cc() As Bitmap

        Dim s As Screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen
        Dim img As New Bitmap(s.Bounds.Width, s.Bounds.Height)
        Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
        gr.CopyFromScreen(s.Bounds.Location, Point.Empty, s.Bounds.Size)
        Return img
    End Function

Comment: helooooooooooooooo

Comment: Did it work? If yes could you please mark as answered? Thanks!