# Returning Image using Image.FromStream

Tags: c#, .net

I know there are similar posts but I haven't got any answer for my problem and hence posting this.

I have a method that retrieves and returns image from a image path. Below is the code snippet I used. This fails in some cases as the image is lost after returning.

```
public static Image GetImageFromPicPath(string strUrl)
{
    WebResponse wrFileResponse;
    wrFileResponse = WebRequest.Create(strUrl).GetResponse();
    using (Stream objWebStream = wrFileResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        return Image.FromStream(objWebStream);
    }
}
```

If I use Bitmap class and return the image, metadata is lost.

If I use MemoryStream (as shown below) and I don't dispose MemoryStream it works . But there is possible memory leak here. If I use using block, the image is lost.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
objWebStream.CopyTo(ms, 8192);
return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Can someone suggest me best approach to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does "the image is lost" mean?

Comment: After retrieving the image I am trying to display it. It gives me GDI+ error (if using first snippet that I mentioned). I am assuming image is lost. Not very sure though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is why it's not working for you (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx) :

[image: Image.FromStream Method remarks: You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.]

Here's a post that covers the issue a bit more: [Loading an image from a stream without keeping the stream open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845456/loading-an-image-from-a-stream-without-keeping-the-stream-open)

Try this:

```
public static Image GetImageFromPicPath(string strUrl)
{
    using (WebResponse wrFileResponse = WebRequest.Create(strUrl).GetResponse())
    using (Stream objWebStream = wrFileResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
        objWebStream.CopyTo(ms, 8192);
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); 
    }
}
```

In your consuming code do something like this:

```
using (var image = GetImageFromPicPath("http://imgur.com/123456.png"))
{
    //use image
}
```

By wrapping "var image" in a using statement, Dispose() will be called on image which will also Dispose() and release the underlying MemoryStream in use by the Image.

Comment: This is awesome, except it "throws": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416

Answer (score 3):

Use the `MemoryStream` and don't explicitly close it.  The `Bitmap` will close it in its `Dispose` method.  There's no memory leak, as long as you remember to `Dispose()` the `Bitmap` when you're done with it.  (And even if you didn't, the `MemoryStream` would eventually get garbage collected provided you let go of the `Bitmap` at some point and the `Bitmap`'s the only thing holding a reference to it.)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814675