# Convert input stream to image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, amazon-s3, data-conversion

I am try to convert inputstream to Image

I have tried using the below code.

```
var img = Image.FromStream(imagePathErrorMessage.StreamObject);
```

I need to pass the img to mvc view

```
 @foreach (var img in imageSet)
                                    {
                                        <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-inline">
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" onchange="DisplayedImageOnchange(this)" value="@img.Id" />
                                                <img src="@img.Url" class="img-thumbnail" />
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="btn-block">
                                                <input type="file" class="replace file-loading" />
                                                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete">delete</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }

 public JsonResult Upload(object model)
        { 
            var img = Image.FromStream(imagePathErrorMessage.StreamObject);

            return Json(new AdCreative { Id = 100, Url = Url.Content("data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String('" + img + "')") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

it throws the following error :

[image]

the above inputstream from amazon s3 response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may find more information by clicking on 'View Detail' in the exception window, and expanding any `InnerException` properties.

Have you checked that `imagePathErrorMessage.StreamObject` is non-null and provides an image in one of the accepted formats?

These are JPG, BMP, TIF, GIF and PNG. If your image contains transparency data, you should convert it to a PNG first. You may not use RAW data, for that I think you'd want `BitmapImage` instead of `Image`

If the stream is valid, it will also need to be at position 0 before you start the read, for example:

```
imagePathErrorMessage.StreamObject.Position = 0;
var img = Image.FromStream(imagePathErrorMessage.StreamObject);
```

Edit for OP Edit:

Do you need to set the ResponseStream back to position zero *after* it is converted but *before* it is copied to `destination`?

(if at the breakpoint shown in your screenshot, you hovered over `destination` would it show a stream with 61153 length and CurrentPosition 0?)

Second Edit:

This answered post [Loading an image from a stream without keeping the stream open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845456/loading-an-image-from-a-stream-without-keeping-the-stream-open) describes why when using Image.FromStream then the stream needs to remain open for the lifetime of the image.

Comment: yes I have set the StreamObject.Position= 0 before copying.

Comment: Well, if you have certified at the point of `Image.FromStream(imagePathErrorMessage.StreamObject);` that your stream object is valid, with a non zero length, and at position zero, then the only other thing I can suggest is that the data in that stream is not convertable to one of the supported image types.

Comment: One final suggestion, it appears that the stream object must remain open during the lifetime of the `Image`