# C# Out of Memory when Creating Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, bitmap, screenshot

I'm creating an application (Windows Form) that allows the user to take a screenshot based on the locations they choose (drag to select area). I wanted to add a little "preview pane" thats zoomed in so the user can select the area they want more precisely (larger pixels). On a mousemove event i have a the following code...

```
private void falseDesktop_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        zoomBox.Image = showZoomBox(e.Location);
        zoomBox.Invalidate();
        bmpCrop.Dispose();
    }

private Image showZoomBox(Point curLocation)
    {
        Point start = new Point(curLocation.X - 50, curLocation.Y - 50);
        Size size = new Size(100, 90);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(start, size);
        Image selection = cropImage(falseDesktop.Image, rect);
        return selection;
    }

private static Bitmap bmpCrop;
private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
    {
        if (cropArea.Width != 0 && cropArea.Height != 0)
        {
            Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
            bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
            bmpImage.Dispose();
            return (Image)(bmpCrop);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The line that fails and has the Out of Memory exception is:

```
bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
```

Basically what this does is it takes a 100x90 rectangle around the mouse pointer and pulls that into the zoomBox, which is a picturebox control. However, in the process, i get an Out Of Memory error. What is it that i am doing incorrectly here?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: On what line is your exception being thrown?

Comment: Are you ever disposing bmpCrop?

Comment: And why are you creating a new cropped image on **each mouse move** instead of reusing an existing image?

Comment: @Steve, edit: stated the line thats being thrown to the OP

@CodeInChaos, I do dispose of it right after the zoomBox.Invalidate(); Sorry i excluded it, will add to op.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, because i need the updated image/position of the mouse.

Comment: That's the wrong place to dispose it since there is no one-to-one relationship between `Invalidate` calls and paint events. You should dispose it directly before assigning a new value to the `cropImage` field. Or better reuse the old bitmap and just fill it with the new content.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Out of memory in C# imaging, is usually sign of wrong rect or point - **a bit of red herring**. I bet `start` has **negative X or Y** when error happens or **the Size.Hight + Y or Size.Width + X is bigger than Hight or width of the image**.

Comment: Looking at the code that certainly is possible.  start.x is curPos.X - 50 (same for y value).  So what happens when curPos.x or curPos.y of less than 50?

Comment: I checked that, and i think you might be right, i was trying from the edge of the screen.... So what i did was tried it from the middle and that error went away yet another came up. Parameter is Not Valid. in my Program.cs -- Line Application.Run(); (i have no actual form thats being used, its just a notification icon application.

Answer (score 9):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) explains that an `OutOfMemoryException` means

> `rect` is outside of the source bitmap bounds

where `rect` is the first parameter to the `Bitmap.Clone` method.

So check that the `cropArea` parameter is not larger than your image.

In GDI+ an `OutOfMemoryException` does not really mean "out of memory"; the GDI+ error code `OufOfMemory` has been overloaded to mean different things. The reasons for this are historic and a well described by Hans Passant in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610416/is-there-a-reason-image-fromfile-throws-an-outofmemoryexception-for-an-invalid-im/2610506#2610506).

Comment: In that case I would expect .net to do the checking of the passed in rectangle before passing the code on the GDI+ and throw an appropriate exception if the rectangle is invalid.

Comment: In my case My form had small window but the image had large width $ height than form. While the from's BackgroundImageLayout mode was Tile. Upon setting BackgroundImageLayout to center my problem was gone.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Bitmap object like this:

```
using (Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img))
{
    // Do something with the Bitmap object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check if curLocation.X is larger than 50, otherwise your rectangle will start in the negative area (and of course curLocation.Y)

Comment: Yeah i need to add that to my code, however that was still not the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the zoom box goes off the edge of the desktop area, then when you try to crop, you are asking the system to make a new image that includes pixels outside of the video memory area.  Make sure to limit your zoom box so that none of its extents is less than 0 or greater than the screen edges.

Answer (score -2):

If you are creating new bitmaps over and over, you might need to call `GC.Collect();` which will force C# to garbage collect

Comment: I think Bitmaps use unmanaged memory, so Dispose should take care of the memory.

Comment: Tried calling GC.Collect Right before  zoomBox.Image = showZoomBox(e.Location); in the mouse move even and still fails.

Comment: Instead of GC.Collect you should Dispose() the bitmaps that you don't need anymore!