# C# out of memory error

Tags: memory

I've been trying for hours to figure this out. When this executes it will run until system runs out of memory. 
I tried disposing the bmp's created after used, it made no difference.
I also tried disposing the webbrowser but then I need to run the webpage on a loop with the right height/width etc to take a capture of it. 
I tried creating a new webbrowser everything it loops then dispose but it then wouldn't work. 
Can anyone see what may be happening here?

The loop:

```
        wbcondor1.AllowNavigation = true;
        wbcondor1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wbcondor1_DocumentCompleted);
        wbcondor1.Navigate("blanked out");
```

the document completed

```
  private void wbcondor1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap condor1bmp = new Bitmap(600, 1000);
        wbcondor1.DrawToBitmap(condor1bmp, new Rectangle(wbcondor1.Location.X, wbcondor1.Location.Y, wbcondor1.Width, wbcondor1.Height));

        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 558)) == "Color [A=255, R=232, G=30, B=48]") { c1to1.Text = "lower"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 584)) == "Color [A=255, R=232, G=30, B=48]") { c1to2.Text = "lower"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 608)) == "Color [A=255, R=232, G=30, B=48]") { c1to3.Text = "lower"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 633)) == "Color [A=255, R=232, G=30, B=48]") { c1to4.Text = "lower"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 658)) == "Color [A=255, R=232, G=30, B=48]") { c1to5.Text = "lower"; }

        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 558)) == "Color [A=255, R=0, G=175, B=88]") { c1to1.Text = "higher"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 584)) == "Color [A=255, R=0, G=175, B=88]") { c1to2.Text = "higher"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 608)) == "Color [A=255, R=0, G=175, B=88]") { c1to3.Text = "higher"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 633)) == "Color [A=255, R=0, G=175, B=88]") { c1to4.Text = "higher"; }
        if (Convert.ToString(condor1bmp.GetPixel(553, 658)) == "Color [A=255, R=0, G=175, B=88]") { c1to5.Text = "higher"; }
        // bmp.Save("condor1.gif");
        condor1bmp.Dispose();
    }
```

Thanks all, hopefully someone can see what I'm missing :(

Comment: Comment out each part of your logic until the leak disappears.  For example, comment out the body of `wbcondor1_DocumentCompleted()` -- do you still run out of memory eventually?

Comment: didnt even think of doing that. Just did it and it will still run out, just keeps building with every loop

Comment: Then this block is not the source of your problem.  Run your code in a profiler and look for huge allocations, or a huge number of small allocations, then try to track down where they are coming from.

Comment: well the code is really simple now, its just a webbrowser and the command to goto x website every x seconds :s

Comment: Then perhaps the browser history is growing too large.  Use the profiler, Luke.

Answer (score 0):

If an Exception is thrown,

```
condor1bmp.Dispose();
```

will not be called.

Always use a *using* statement to wrap things that implement *IDisposable*.

Other than that, there are plenty of things that can cause an OutOfMemoryException when working with a Bitmap, other than actually running out of memory.

For several possibilities, see

[C# Out of Memory when Creating Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318563/c-sharp-out-of-memory-when-creating-bitmap)

Is it possible that your stress test is hitting one of those conditions?

Comment: i just commented out the document completed part and it still rises which means everytime i tell the webbrowser to refresh the page the memory builds each time

Answer (score 0):

Just to let people know who run into this error. Ran out of memory on line x. It is a problem with internet explorer itself. It can be stopped by turning of active scripting in IE settings to disable javascript.