# Out of Memory with image processing but have lots of RAM

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, out-of-memory

I am getting `Out of Memory exception` in my C# application while processing images. I am testing it on my computer where I have 8GB of ram, way more than used by the app.

I've checked the `GC.TotalMemory(false)`. Before the processing runs it says (converted to MB) **2MB**, after without waiting for the garbage collection it says **4MB**. While processing it reaches **81 MB** at the peak.

I first thought that it something to do with the binding restrictions, because it works inside a WCF service, but didn't find any parameter that can lead to that exception.

I think that my application should have no problem running with 81MP memory used at the peak, and even more. What I am doing wrong? -- Thanks.

The loop that runs the processing:

```
Parallel.For(0, count, i =>
   {
      Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(proxy.BeginSaveImage(sp, new AsyncCallback(CompleteSave), state), proxy.EndSaveImage).ContinueWith(result => {});
});
```

Runs in parallel and calls the image processing method asynchronously.

Comment: Could you post some code? Does your program have recursion?

Comment: Which OS is that on ?

Comment: Can you compile as a 64-bit app and try again?

Comment: Get callstack...At least you'll see where it happens and if it is your code or not...

Comment: Running on Windows 7 OS. I run the code that process image in a loop. I will provide a code..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov how do I get the callstack?

Comment: @Enigmativity how can I compile it as 64-bit app. It's a .NET web project?

Comment: @IdanShechter - By copy and pasting the code into a 64-bit app project? That wouldn't be a bad way to test your code and to make sure you are writing it in a modular fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Legacy reasons, Image.FromFile will throw out of memory exceptions for image files it cannot read.
See [Is there a reason Image.FromFile throws an OutOfMemoryException for an invalid image format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610416/is-there-a-reason-image-fromfile-throws-an-outofmemoryexception-for-an-invalid-i)

Your png may be invalid and throwing out of memory exceptions for similar reasons