# Check if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, gdi+

I'm loading a picture from a file and then create a new `Bitmap`. Everything works fine but I want to secure more my app.

I'm using Bitmap Constructor (Stream)

```
public Bitmap(
    Stream stream
)
```

I would like to check if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

```
public static Image FromFile(
    string filename,
    bool useEmbeddedColorManagement
)
```

`Image.FromFile` throws `OutOfMemoryException` if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

But I would like to avoid using `Image.FromFile`, because I won't allocate memory etc.

So the question is: how can I check if GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `try/catch`. I doubt you didn't thought about it, but it's not clear why you can't use it.

Comment: It did not *actually* run out of memory.  So nothing to worry about.  Why these exceptions are bogus is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610506/17034).

Comment: @Sinatr I worry about GDI+ and pixel format.

Comment: @HansPassant The same issue as above.

Comment: How far up do I need to look??  If you don't understand the post I linked then just assume that *nothing to worry about* applies.

Comment: But is there any way to check GDI+ format?

Comment: @Cieja Just do a try-catch around loading the image from file, as Sinatr said from the start. And make sure to dispose the image if the load does succeed.